# How to handle FadeInImage.assetNetwork exception when url is wrong?

Tags: ios, flutter

I'm using FadeInImage to show the internet image.

```
FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
                placeholder: 'assets/images/default_360_360.png',
                image: widget.model.image,
                height: ScreenUtil.fitWidthStatic(320),
                width: ScreenUtil.fitWidthStatic(320),
                imageErrorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) {
                  return Image.asset(
                    'assets/images/default_360_360.png',
                    height: ScreenUtil.fitWidthStatic(320),
                    width: ScreenUtil.fitWidthStatic(320),
                  );
                },
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
```

It works well when the url is correct, but when  using a wrong url ,the output print the error message.

```
════════ Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════
type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'List<int>' in type cast
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

The exception is throwed from network_image_io.
What's even stranger is when navigate to another widget, It also print the exception message.Even  another widget didn't using FadeInImage. It seems repaint the element.
So how can i fix it?
Thanks.